# Hamiltonian Cycles of a graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Prove if this statement is true: every graph consisting of two edge-disjoint Hamiltonian paths contains a Hamiltonian cycle.

Two edge-disjoint Hamiltonian paths means all vertices can be connected with two different paths of no edges in common; so the graph has at least 2(n-1) edges in total if the graph has n vertices. I am not sure how to relate this to hamilton cycle (how to add one more edge to the path to make it a cycle.)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the graph a = b = c where = represents two edges.
a - b - c, the upper Hamiltonian path and a _ b _ c, the lower Hamiltonian path, are edgewise disjoint.
There is no Hamiltonian cycle.

Comment: this is a simple graph theres only one edge

Comment: @jamesblack What simple graph?